# Changing element visibility on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently trying to remove the visibility of a few elements inside a side menu on toggle. I am currently using `Bootstrap 4` and I'm quite unsure how to do it with the newly implemented changes. Here is a JS Fiddle on what I've currently done: [Fiddle Number 1](http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/398/)

I am trying to change the visibility of text inside the `li` elements, so that when the button is not clicked, they are not visible on the menu.

I've tried using this code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$("#menu-toggle").toggle(
    function(){$("span").css({"visibility": "visible"});},
    function(){$("span").css({"visibility": "hidden"});},
});
```

How can I hide and display the text inside the span with toggling the button?

Comment: you have an `r` in `visibilityr`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen the typo is not causing the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this css code

```
.toggled span {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

this will make the spans visible when the side bar is toggled

[**See updated jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/399/)

Comment: nailed it!. Can I ask, is this something new in `Bootstrap 4` IS transition applicable as well?

Comment: No, this is just a template :), i think its from startbootstrap right!